# Converting Files from Markdown to Word Docx

Tags: python, markdown, docx, pandoc

I have a folder called Project:

Project:

img
docs
README
The README is written in Markdown and looks like this:

```
# xxxxxxxx

## Content

## 1. [xxxxxxxx](docs/1.md)
## 1.1 [xxxxxxxx](docs/11.md)
## 2. [xxxxxxxx](docs/2.md)
### 2.1 [xxxxxxxx](docs/21.md)
### 2.2 [xxxxxxxx](docs/22.md)
#### 2.2.1 [xxxxxxxx](docs/221.md)
#### 2.2.2 [xxxxxxxx](docs/222.md)
### 2.3 [xxxxxxxx](docs/23.md)
### 2.4. [xxxxxxxx](docs/24.md)
### 2.5. [xxxxxxxx](docs/25.md)
### 2.6. [xxxxxxxx](docs/26.md)
## 3. [xxxxxxxx](docs/3.md)
### 3.1. [xxxxxxxx](docs/31.md)
#### 3.1.1 [xxxxxxxx](docs/311.md)
#### 3.1.2 [xxxxxxxx](docs/312.md)
#### 3.1.3 [xxxxxxxx](docs/313.md)
#### 3.1.4 [xxxxxxxx](docs/314.md)
### 3.2 [xxxxxxxx](docs/32.md)
#### 3.2.1 [xxxxxxxx](docs/321.md)
#### 3.2.2. [xxxxxxxx](docs/322.md)
### 3.3. [xxxxxxxx](docs/33.md)
#### 3.3.1. [xxxxxxxx](/docs/331.md)
#### 3.3.2. [xxxxxxxx](/docs/322.md)
## 4. [xxxxxxxx](/docs/4.md)
### 4.1 [xxxxxxxx](docs/41.md)
### 4.2 [xxxxxxxx](docs/42.md)
### 4.3 [xxxxxxxx](docs/43.md)
### 4.4 [xxxxxxxx](docs/44.md)
## 5. [xxxxxxxx](/docs/5.md)
## 6. [Exxxxxxxx](/docs/6.md)

## [xxxxxxxx](docs/a_shorts.en)
```

The documents have images that come from the img folder and have cross references to each other e.g. Document 1 has a reference to Document 11.

How can I write a python script which uses pandoc to convert the documents as they appear in order in the README to a DOCX file and combine them to a single file?

I tried a python script:

```
import os

def create_markdown_files_list(folder_path):
    markdown_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".md"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                markdown_files.append(file_path)
    return markdown_files

markdown_files = create_markdown_files_list("docs")
output_file = "output.docx"

os.system("pandoc " + " ".join(markdown_files) + " -o " + output_file)
```

But this script does not read the README file. I want to make sure that the order from the README is ensured in the complete document.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want the file order to be defined by a file and not their order in the directory, you'll have to read that README.md file and then use that to tell pandoc what to do.

(I didn't test this but the idea is one way to get you there)

```py
order_of_files = []
with open("README.md") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # logic here to determine if this line is what you want 
        # if it is, then you have to parse the line for the file name 
        # and add it to the list that has the order you want
        file_path = process_the_line_somehow(line)
        order_of_files.append(file_path)

# once you have the order you want, you can let pandoc to the heavy lifting
os.system(f'pandoc -s {" ".join(order_of_files)} -o output.docx")
```

The `-s` (standalone) option for pandoc will combine all the files into 1 file